# attr() not working with appended img in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am not able to get the src attribute of the image that i created using the .append method in Jquery. I am able to get src when i type the element in html file but not when i append it. In short the alert method at the end of below code doesnt give the src of the img.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="createlm()">click</button>
<div class="row"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
//function to append img element..

function createlm(){
    $(".row").append("<img src='image/Chrysanthemum.jpg' width='100px' height='100px'>");
};
```

//function to get src attribute

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".row>img").click(function(){
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
        alert(imgsrc);
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure that your selector is correct because it can return more than one image, if you append more than once.

Comment: If its possible use console.log(imgsrc); to check your object at developers tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function to get src attribute is added to all `.row>img` elements *before* you have a chance to click the button create an image.

You could reattach the click event after the image is added, but a better way might be to attach the listener to some parent element that will always exist. You can do that like this:

```
$('.row').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    alert(imgsrc);
});
```

Even if images are added after this event handler, the handler will still execute.